# Was Reviewer badge promoted from Silver to Mithril?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-badges

I [already noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144109/silver-reviewer-badge-much-harder-than-gold-electorate-why) that the Reviewer badge seems like a heck of a lot of work for a paltry silver. It now looks like I may have been understating the matter. Apparently it’s even harder than I thought, since I have over 1,000 reviews (and probably over 1,000 actioned reviews, too), yet [I still have no such mythical badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist?tab=badges&sort=class).  Here are quasi-current stats for ELU.SE:

[image: ELU reviewer stats]

Is the reviewer badge not being awarded during the new review beta, or is this a bug? Is it somehow because it’s on ELU not SO? Why would that matter? Even if it did, it should be easier not harder, since all the numbers were set up to fit the Trilogy, not the little guys.

I’ve waited something like 32 hours now, and still no sign of it.  **What in the world is this badge made of anyway, *mithril***?  I guess that would fit with the mythic theme of the unobtainable, but what do you have to do to get this silly thing, anyway?  Vanquish a balrog in Moria to get at his stash of true-silver? Sail into the uttermost West with  a Silmaril to guide me on my errand?

I feel like undying doom has been been laid upon me: to seek forever a tiny badge that glimmers as faint as a distant star, but never any closer to it draw.

*A ship then new they built for him

          of mithril and of elvenglass

          with crystal keel; no shaven oar

          nor sail she bore, on silver mast

          the Silmaril as lantern light

          and banner bright with living flame

          of fire unstained by Elbereth

          herself was set, who thither came

          and wings immortal made for him,

          and laid on him undying doom,

          to sail the shoreless skies and come

          behind the Sun and light of Moon.*

Comment: Looks like you meant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144109/silver-reviewer-badge-much-harder-than-gold-electorate-why in your first link. Weren't you?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yup, mouse farts.  Fixed.

Comment: Must..resist...deleting...(admittedly entertaining)...fluff....

Comment: Not Mithril but lead. Gravity took it from your profile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I can tell you are looking at the *new* review tool which is still in beta and does not contribute to the count for the badge.

You want: https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers that will take you to the old review tool which will contribute to the badge count. Your progress for the badge is indicated on the right hand side of this tool and can be seen to increment each time you click "review post." You must review 1000 posts from here and action >=200 of them.

Comment: Also, of those 1,000 reviews, 200 must be *actioned*, meaning a vote, edit, etc. took place.

Comment: @Gaffi no. Not all 1000 must be actioned. Only >200 must be.

Comment: Only 200 of the 1000 reviews need to be action.

Comment: </foot in mouth> Yup, I screwed up there. (Still good to point out, though. -- edited to correct the numbers.)

Comment: added to answer.

Comment: If it doesn't contribute....well that's really lame.

Comment: @BenBrocka it's a *beta*

Comment: @wax: I sure hope it will count retroactively once it's out of beta, because by that time there won't be anything left to review.

Answer (score 0):

The new review badges ([Custodian](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/125/custodian)/[Reviewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/106/reviewer)/[Steward](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/126/steward)), which applied to the *new* review system, were implemented on Sept 21, 2012. As such, [you earned Reviewer for Low Quality Posts on Sept 21](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/106/reviewer?userid=2085), and then again for Close Votes soon after.