# Were there any occurrences when a badge's class was changed?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm just curious whether there was a precedent of changing a badge's class.

I am aware of [the retirement of the Documentation badges on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/3151675); but, strictly speaking, that wasn't a direct class change.

Comment: Do you mean a bronze badge becoming silver/gold, silver becoming bronze/gold or gold becoming bronze/silver?

Comment: @Oded Correct, I was using the wrong terminology. Edited my question.

Comment: Retirement's happened before, I don't think badges have been transmuted downwards before tho

Comment: The [Reviewer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144109/295232) used to be awarded in a really different way, but its class hasn't changed.